# Meaning of "push onto" in the given context

Tags: meaning

Here is the sentence:

> This transparent blue block turns into a real one that you can **push**
>   **onto** a switch to open a door.

The text is a description of a video game.

Comment: that you can use to push a latch to open the door. Doors don't usually open with a "switch"; They open with a latch or handle. switches are for train tracks.

Answer (score 1):

When I google your sentence, the search engine offers me:

> This transparent blue block turns into a real one that you can push **into** a switch to open a door

along with a great many cartoons and other video images.

So I would interpret the instruction to mean that a block of semi-transparent blue turns opaque and can then be moved sideways across the screen to make contact with the switch.

The use of **onto** would indicate that the movement was vertically down on to the switch rather than horizontally across towards it.

As I'm not familiar with the game, I can't be sure.

Comment: It's very poor English. Many of these games are written by non-English speakers and are full of weird s****.